# MySqlParameterCollection: How to add an explicit true/false value of a parameter for JSON boolean?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am building a MySQL command using the MySqlParameterCollection class, but I am trying to query a boolean field that is extracted from a json column.
that is, it is a JSON boolean. 
if I use the MySqlParameterCollection to add it, and even if I specify the type to be boolean, the query that ultimately runs looks like this:

SELECT jdoc FROM audits WHERE (JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, '$.myFlag') = 0 )

which is fine for mysql boolean, but the field is a json boolean, and it only works if I run this query:

SELECT jdoc FROM audits WHERE (JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, '$.myFlag') = false/true )

My question is, can I somehow use MySqlParameterCollection to add the param value explicitly (true/false), or do I have to bake it into the query myself?
(not the end of the world, since it is a constant predefined set of values).

Thanks,
Roy.

Comment: I am using MySql.Data 6.10.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an acceptable answer:
While I couldn't find a way of doing this from MySQL.Data, I was able to solve this from the query side:
you can use the CAST function to cast the JSON boolean into a numeric value (which is what MySQL boolean is).
so since you control the creation of the query you can use the cast function in case your parameter is boolean

for example:

```
SELECT jdoc 
FROM audits 
WHERE CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(jdoc, '$.myFlag') AS UNSIGNED) = 0;
```

note that you cannot cast into any MySQL type, but the numeric SIGNED/UNSIGNED works well (see CAST doc.)